# How to use `resource_class.omniauth_providers` outside devise view template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using `resource_class` in devise view partial template like this.

```
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Connect to #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{provider.to_s} omniauth" %>
  <% end -%>
```

It works fine. But when I load this partial from another model's view, I get this error.

```
undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for #<#<Class:0x007fa29be245d8>:0x007fa29bdf3708>
```

What should I do to use `resource_class` from another model's view?

I want to make user possible to signup everywhere in my app with modal dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `resource_class.omniauth_providers`, you could try `Devise.omniauth_providers` if you're ok with a reference to Devise in your view (it's perhaps not as nice as going via the resource_class).  It will return the same list of providers, assuming that the ones you've set up using the `config.omniauth` parameter in your `devise.rb` initialiser are the same as the `:omniauth_providers` list in your user model.  If not, or if you have multiple user model classes and they don't all allow login using the same providers and so have different `:omniauth_providers` listed, then this wouldn't be appropriate for you but I'm guessing that's unlikely.